# Why are my Czechoslovakian Characters not rendered correctly in perl::CGI/ popup_menu?

Tags: perl, cgi

I created two popup_menus in different ways that contains czech Characters. 
Here's my code:

```
my  @locations  = ('České Budějovice', 'Jakubské náměstí', 'Nové Město na Moravě');
my  $location1  = popup_menu(-name=>'Location', -values=>[@locations]);

my  $location2  = "<select name=\"location\">";
foreach my $loc (sort @locations){
    $location2 .= "<option value=\"\">" . $loc . "</option>";
}
    $location2 .= "</select>";
```

Output from $location2 (as expected):

```
České Budějovice
Jakubské náměstí
Nové Město na Moravě
```

but from $location1 especially some 'hatchek'-chars where replaced by questionmarks:

```
České Bud?jovice
Jakubské nám?stí
Nové M?sto na Morav?
```

Q: Why are my characters not rendered correctly?

Comment: Just so you know the HTML generation functions in CGI are advised against in the docs: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used "The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns. See CGI::Alternatives for an example of using CGI.pm with the Template::Toolkit module."

Comment: What happens if you replace the non-ASCII characters with their &#XXX; equivalents?

Comment: And since you have non-ASCII characters in your code do you also have a "use utf8;" at the top of the code?

Comment: use utf8 <- Life can be that simple ...

Comment: `use utf8` tells `perl` that the source code is encoded in UTF-8. When you use that, you should make sure that the source file is indeed encoded in UTF-8 and not some other encoding.

Comment: Are these from the same source code file or different ones? What encodings do those files use? Do the source code files include `use utf8`? Where are you getting the output from - is it from a command line shell or in a browser? Do the CGI programs emit any headers that define the encoding of the output? There is so much information missing from this question that it is impossible to do anything but guess at a solution.